# Duda sobre fecha c#

Tags: c#

mi duda es de como se puede hacer para controlar 
que una persona sea mayor a 25 cuando esa persona me 
ingresa su fecha de nacimiento.

```
 public DateTime Fecha
    {
        get { return fecha; }
        set { fecha = value; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar otra propiedad asi:

```
public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

public bool IsMayorDeEdad
{
    get
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        // Calculate the age.
        var age = today.Year - Fecha.Year;
        // Go back to the year the person was born in case of a leap year
        if (Fecha > today.AddYears(-age)) {age--;}
        return age > 25;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con esto:

```
public DateTime Fecha
        {
            get { return fecha; }
            set { 
                  int edad = DateTime.Today.AddTicks(-value.Ticks).Year - 1;
                   if edad>25{
                           fecha = value;
                    }
           }

        }
```

Comment: Hola Ariel, eso de addticks y lo que sigue aun no lo he dado en mi instituto, por algo mas básico como se podría reemplazar